# Graphviz window too small

Tags: linux, kde, graphviz, kwin

I have a script which generates Graphviz graphs and displays them using the `dot -Txlib` command. However, it always appears in a tiny, unreadably-small window, so I have to maximise it each time. How can I make Graphviz open larger windows by default? I am using KDE on Fedora Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Open the application that has too-small windows by default - in this case, Graphviz, but it should work for any such application. In System Settings, go into Window Management -> Window Rules. Click New and then click Detect Window Properties. Then go to the Size and Position tab and enable Maximised Horizontally and Maximised Vertically. Click OK and then Apply. Depending on the policy you have chosen when you enabled Maximise Horizontally and Vertically, this should open all new windows of the same type with the desired size.